# Get just X number of strings from a comma separated cel

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

having real trouble finding a succinct solution to this simple problem. Currently I have cells which contain many comma separated items. I just want the first 5.

ie. cell A1 =

```
text, another string, something else, here's another one, guess what another string here, and another, hello i'm another string, another string etc, etc, etccccc
```

and I'm trying to grab just the first 5 strings.

Beyond that, I wonder if I can incorporate a formula such as `=LEN(A1)>20`

Currently I do this with numerous; `=IFERROR(INDEX( SPLIT(C31,","),1))` then `=IFERROR(INDEX( SPLIT(C31,","),2))` etc. then run the LEN formula above.

Is there a simpler solution? Thanks so much.

Comment: Text to columns and copy the first five columns to a new sheet?  Does this need to be a formula?

Comment: also, because you're using the `SPLIT` function, i'm assuming this is google sheets and not excel?

Comment: @tigeravatar sorry I wasn't aware SPLIT was a google sheets 'thing', sorry, yes I'm using google sheets. thought I have Excel here also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 =split(replace(A1, find("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1, ", ", "|", 5)), len(A1), ""), ", ", false)
```

Comment: and if I wanted the results in one cell, I've worked out I can use:
 
=JOIN(replace(B2, find("|", SUBSTITUTE(B2, ", ", "|", 4)), len(B2), ""), "", )

Answer (score 1):

For **Excel**, with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

To get all 5 substrings into a single cell, use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(1),5))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A1,","),1,5)
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"((?:.*?,){5})")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REPT("(.*?),",5))
```

- SPLIT to split by delimiter
- ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to constrain the array
- REGEX<sup>[1](https://www.regex101.com)</sup> to extract 5 comma separated values

  - `.` Any character
  - `.*?`, Any character repeated unlimited number of times (`?` as little as possible) followed by a `,`
  - `{5}` Quantifier
- REPT to repeat strings